# what i can do with error : permission denied in hosting service

Tags: php, linux, hosting, permission-denied

i registered in one of the free hosting service i have a problem with extracting files , in panel of host i haven't facility for extract files so 
i just write a script in php to do this , but i got this error : permission denied ! so in your idea can i do anything (like changing permission)  or it should do with Linux administrator ???
(i can just do chmode to change the access permission on files and folders)

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('main.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/myzip/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem lies in the file permissions, not in the code. If this is the case, this question belongs on Super User.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang , i have a facility in panel to change  file permissions by chmode and i set them to 777 but still i get the error for root directory but for one up directory of root i haven't that problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code line `$zip->extractTo('/myzip/');` implies you are extracting against root directory of the file system or your assigned chroot. You might not have permissions to do so - try this instead:

```
$zip->extractTo('./myzip/');
```

Comment: no it couldn't do any change still i have  that error ! what the meaning of ./ i saw ../ before but ./ no !

Comment: but ../ works thanks i think your mean is same ../ !! so why ?! i have permission to folder that up of the root but i haven't permission to root !? this permission is relate to same chmode permissions ?? i set the permission for root to 777 but again i have the problem !

Comment: difference between ../ and ./ is that first means "one directory up" and second means "same directory". This means you probably have permission to write the parent directory of the current directory. 

Point being, it's a permission problem and you should see whether you allowed to write those directories you are using.